# Parallel computing NInverseFourierTransForm

Tags: parallelization

I am running the code below, and it works perfectly. I have some function in Fourier space, and I take the numerical `InverseFourierTransform`. However, I will have to repeat this calculation often, and therefore I want to use `ParallelTable`. I've tried this, by replacing `Table` in the code below by `ParallelTable`. I am running the code on a computer with 8 kernels. Surprisingly, using `ParallelTable` doesn't speed up the calculation. I simply find almost the same computation time (not roughly a factor 8 difference)!

Can anybody explain to me what the reason for this is? I've tested the `ParallelTable` with commands like

```
  ParallelTable[Pause[1]; f[i], {i, 4}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

and for this case it works fine, but not for the `NInverseFourierTransform`.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
f[q_] := Sqrt[2/Pi]*(-Sinc[q] + Cos[q]);
k[q_] := Sqrt[Pi/2]/Abs[q];
a = 10^-2;
b = 10^-2;
Needs["FourierSeries`"]
hfourierdomain[ω_] = a*f[ω]*k[ω]/(1 + b*ω^2*k[ω]);
displ = Table[{j, NInverseFourierTransform[hfourierdomain[ω], ω, j]}, {j, -5, 5, 1/60}];
```

Comment: If you have a recent NVidia Graphics Card, you may use CUDAFourier which is much faster and easy to install/use. (May be there's nothing to install, I can't remember)

Comment: @andre I think `NInverseFourierTransform` relies on `NIntegrate` internally, not on `Fourier`.  It works on a numerical black-box function, not on a list of numbers.  So `CUDAFourier` might not be useful here (it is of course a good replacement for `Fourier`)

Comment: @Szabolcs Agree. I have `Fourier[]` and `FourierTransform[]` mixed up.

Comment: Use ParallelNeeds[] for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run your code on my machine with `Table` (not `ParallelTable`), I see that all the cores of the CPU are used by a single MathKernel process. This means that internally `NInverseFourierTransform` uses an operation that is already parallelized.   Certain operations, such as `LinearSolve`, will be able to use all cores of your CPU even when run on a single kernel.

Because of this the `Table` version is likely already as efficient as it can be, and splitting the task into several parts and distributing it among kernels (which will individually all want to use all your CPU cores) is likely to just reduce performance.

P.S.  If your CPU has 4 cores and supports hyperthreading (e.g. many i7 processors), your OS will show 8 cores in total out of which 4 are working.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for this helpful information! This also explains to me why parallelization for some expressions does speed up the calculations, and why it never wanted to work for NInverseFourierTransform. I am running the code on some cluster that has (I am not sure) 4 CPU's.

Comment: @user5613 If you are running the code on a cluster and you are able to launch Mathematica kernels on more than one machine, then ParallelTable should be useful.  Just make sure you launch a single subkernel per machine.  How to do this well on various types of clusters is a good question on its own ...

Comment: @user5613 Also, sometimes parallelization doesn't speed up much computations because the problem is not broken into appropriately sized chunks.  In this case manually tuning the Method option of Parallelize may help (but this doesn't apply to your particular problem).  I couldn't get `Outer` to speed up the other day ... (with Parallelize --- there's no ParallelOuter, but Parallelize does work with Outer)

Comment: Hi Szabolcs, I will check tomorrow if I can maybe run Mathematica on more than one machine.. Either case, initially I thought this problem would be ideally to parallize as you don't need any information from 'previous calculations' in this loop. Thanks a lot!